# Use computed property names as export function name

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I know that you can do the following:

```
let name = 'testFunc'
let functions = {
  [name] () {...}
}
```

But is it possible to do something like this:

`export function [name] () {...}`

Comment: I'm doubtful, because that would make for dynamic names for exports, which is like having variable variable names

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly ? This looks like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Using dynamic bindings is likely to prevent lots of compiler optimizations, and is rarely the good solution to another problem. And your specific example is probably not possible (see answer from Saraband)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not possible. [`import`, `export` and module dependencies in general are resolved before runtime](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6391). At the time your module is imported from another module, your variable `name` has no meaning.